# using AND , OR in the query without Interference

Tags: php, mysql

what is the best way to write a query that combines AND , OR without any interference
for example

```
sql= " select * from table where category=5 AND itme_name LIKE %$x% OR item_detail LIKE %x% " ;
```

waht i want is something like

```
 category=5 AND ( itme_name LIKE %$x% OR item_detail LIKE %$x%  )
```

ican do this by using 2 query 
OR SOMETHING LIKE

```
select * from table where category=5 AND category IN(
select category from table where itme_name LIKE %$x% OR item_detail LIKE %x% )
```

but i wonder if i can do this without that inner query by i dont know maybe  using Parenthesis around second part?

Comment: What the hell is interference? `category=5 AND ( itme_name LIKE %$x% OR item_detail LIKE %$x%  )` is, spelling mistakes and the omission of a few `'` aside, a perfectly acceptable `WHERE` predicate. It's acceptable before you substitute $x in, even.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use parentheses to change the [precedence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations) (without parentheses AND has higher precedence than OR):

```
category=5 AND (itme_name LIKE '%$x%' OR item_detail LIKE '%$x%')
```

Notes:

- I've also added missing quotes and a dollar sign.
- Be careful: `itme_name` is most likely incorrectly spelled. It probably should be `item_name`. You may also need to fix the table definition and all other queries that use the incorrect spelling.

Comment: That not entierly true is it? The fulltext statement I mean. You will not get any good result unless you are searching for a full word. With LIKE you have the posibility to search in the middle of words, and as long as you are indexing the fields you know that you're using LIKE towards then the performance not an issue.

Comment: Yes I see you altered your point slightly :) I can see a use for fulltext on item_details, but not really for product name. I would hate it if I had to remember full product names and not just type parts of it and still get a result

Comment: I never asked for you to remove it, and I was happy with what you had written. All I'm doing is stating a second opinion so that the OP can get different views on things, and then make up his own mind of what is best for him.

Comment: Sorry if you experienced my comments as insulting or something. That was not my intention at all